# undefined method `should' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError) during executing watir-webdriver test script with Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, watir-webdriver

Below is the code I am trying to run using cucumber.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'spec'

Given /^I navigate to Google$/ do
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
  @browser.goto "http://www.google.co.in"
end

When /^I enter Wado into the search field$/ do
  searchField=@browser.text_field(:name,'q')
  searchButton=@browser.button(:name,'btnG')
  searchField.set 'Wado'
  searchButton.click
end

Then /^the text DICOM should be present$/ do
  @browser.div(:id => 'resultStats').wait_until_present
  @browser.text.include?("DICOM").should == true
  @browser.close
end
```

But it is throwing me error like this:
This is what I get after running the test:

**

> Failing Scenarios:        cucumber features\karate.feature:3 #
>   Scenario: Where is the Master?
>   1 scenario (1 failed)      3 steps (1 failed, 2 passed)

**

and the error is:

> **undefined method `should' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)                    ./features/step_definitions/step_karate.rb:18:in`/^the text DICOM
>   should be present$/'
>
>   features\karate.feature:6:in `Then the text DICOM should be present'**

Ruby version is 1.9.3
Help me pls!!

Comment: what version of rspec are you using?

Comment: hey :) only after u asked i realized i hadnt installed rspec.. installed rspec-2.14.1 and it is working fine now.. Thanks alot!!
btw, is there any website or link to learn which command is associated with which gem.. I am new to cucumber and would be happy to know how u assosiated rspec immediately after seeing my description..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the question comments, the problem was because `rspec` was not installed, and `should` is provided by the rspec gem.

My initial question about rspec version was actually because in later versions of rspec, the `should` notation (`something.should be_true`) has fallen out of favour, in preference of `expect` notation (`expect(something).to be_true`).

I (and some others) still prefer the `should` notation.

Comment: Thanks again! Like i asked u previously is there any website or forum where I can learn about the gems.

Comment: well I presume you're learning cucumber from some sort of tutorial - it should cover this stuff. I'm not sure where else you would have gotten the idea to write `should` unless it covered rspec as well.

Comment: ya.. i just tried running a sample cucumber test from a tutorial blog.. Any particular website to start learning with? Any help in guiding to learn it properly would be appreciated..

Comment: Install rspec and add the line in code: require 'rspec-expectations'